# How to get only numeric text in recaptcha?

Tags: recaptcha

In my site its very difficult in some cases that the given text images in Recaptcha are not clear. This lead to reduce the intreset of login into our site. I needs some help on getting only numeric values in recaptcha.

Comment: Which technology you are using to build your website??

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Recaptcha has been designed to avoid any OCR's and automated bot attacks.