# Google Recaptcha Version Doesn't support Type Parameter Change

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I have an implementation of New Google Recaptcha Version 2, which displays Image and Audio type captcha randomly.

I tried making it fix by passing the parameter type:image in the rendering function as below:

```
grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
sitekey: 'something',
type: 'image',
callback: function() { $("#error-captcha").hide(); }
}
);
```

Now can someone help me understanding why I am not getting Only Images in captcha verification, why do still get the audio/text captcha?

Comment: have you tried to add `data-type="image"` to your element? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Comment: In the link that @RobScott has provided the default type is image, is there any need to explicitly specify the type?

Comment: good point. I didn't specify on mine. The images come up first, but on the bottom left you can choose audio (on the captcha)

Comment: Yes I have already refered the link, but if its default vallue is image, then why does it display the Captcha with double text+Audio (randomly), why doesn't show me Image gallery or Number in Image captcha?

Comment: I would assume you can't "force" the user to ONLY use images. What if they're blind?

Comment: In that case he wont be able to see the text as well :P Lol

Comment: @RobScott I would think not blind but hard of sight :)

Comment: On a serious note, i am facing it hard to make it working, if the functionality to chose is given then why doesn't it work?

Comment: From what I've been reading, there's no way to force it (at least I can't find otherwise). You can select theme only. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217123/how-do-get-only-numeric-recaptcha

Comment: The problem with the audio captcha is that it's English only. If your website is not in English and your users do not use English it's annoying.