# How to configure reCaptcha, so its always display number as display text in NopCommerce?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, configuration, recaptcha, nopcommerce

I just need to configure reCaptcha, so it is only display numbers as display text,

no **word** as display text.

I need do this configuration in NopCommerce [3.1]

Answer (score 1):

Google uses "advanced risk analysis techniques, actively considering the user’s entire engagement with the CAPTCHA" to determine how difficult of a puzzle the user deserves.  So there is not configuration setting and most users get simple numbers by default.

Source:
http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2013/10/recaptcha-just-got-easier-but-only-if.html

I've noticed when testing for a while it starts to get suspicious of me and throws some that are near impossible to get right.  Then a few days later it's nicer to me again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [Customize Google Re Captcha in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444933/customize-google-re-captcha-in-perl)

> No, this is not possible.
>
> The reCaptcha system is meant as an easy way to plug in a Captcha to
>   your site. As a side effect, it helps digitizing books by using image
>   snippets from scans as a visual challenge. If only numbers should be
>   displayed, then only such “words” from books could be used that are
>   already known to be numbers. This would void the secondary objective
>   of reCaptcha (helping the transcription of scans).
>
> Using numbers only makes your system less secure (in theory). Whereas
>   an attacking OCR software might have difficulty telling apart a g and
>   9, this now becomes unambiguous.